# Select data based on a criteria then copy rows based that match to a certain critera

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a master file which contains time slots with their respective details. Column L is titled `"Slot Status"`. Column A is a unique number starting from 1-1000 (e.g. `A2=1, A3=2, A3=4 ...`).

On the `"UnSlotted"` Worksheet, users will update information to complete the missing information which will result in the Cells within Column M (Slot Status) changing from `"Info Required"` to `"OK"`.

---

I am currently using the below macro to autofilter Column L for cells containing "info required". Then it copies the found data to worksheet titled `"UnSlotted"`.

I am now looking for a macro which will select rows where Column M contains `"OK"` and will copy these to the `"Master Sheet"` on the row matching the respective Unique number (Column A).
E.G. Unique number ID is `"37"`, copy this row to worksheet "Master" in row where column A Unique number ID is matched.

```
Sub TestTHIS()

    Sheets("UnSlotted").Range("A6:M9999").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets("Master File")

    Dim data_end_row_number As Integer
    data_end_row_number = ws.Range("a2").End(xlDown).Rows.Count

    ws.Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:="Info required", VisibleDropDown:=True

    ws.Range("A2:M9999" & data_end_row_number).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("UnSlotted").Range("A6").PasteSpecial

    Worksheets("Master File").ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: For the UnSlotted worksheet, which column is "Unique number ID" located?

Comment: Column A on both sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.

You might need to change which Columns the filtering ("OK") should be based on. Right now it's Column M for the worksheet "UnSlotted".
You can also change how much of the row that should be copied, (right now it's from column A to AA.

VBA Code:

```
Sub CompareCopyFilter()

Dim CopyFromWorkbook As Workbook
Set CopyFromWorkbook = Workbooks("Master File.xlsm") 'Name the Workbook that should be copied from
Dim CopyToWorkbook As Workbook
Set CopyToWorkbook = Workbooks("Master File.xlsm") 'Name the Workbook that should be copied to
Dim CopyFromSheet As Worksheet
Set CopyFromSheet = CopyFromWorkbook.Worksheets("UnSlotted") 'Name the Worksheet that should be copied from
Dim CopyToSheet As Worksheet
Set CopyToSheet = CopyToWorkbook.Worksheets("Master File") 'Name the Worksheet that should be copied to
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lrowCompare As Long
Dim lrowPasteCopyTo As Long
Dim Val As String
Dim ValCompare As String
Dim j As Long
Dim Test As String
Dim Test2 As String

Dim cl As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim CurrentRow As Long

lrow = CopyFromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in sheet that should be copied from
lrowCompare = CopyToSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in sheet that should be copied from

CopyFromSheet.Activate 'Activate From Sheet
Set rng = CopyFromSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lrow, 1)) 'Set Range to apply filter on
CopyFromSheet.Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="OK", VisibleDropDown:=True 'Filter Column M, based on criteria "OK" in the sheet you want to copy from

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'Loop throug all visible cells in range
    CurrentRow = cl.Row 'Row number for current cell in filtered filter
    Val = CopyFromSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, "A").Value 'Get the value from the cell you want to copy from
    For j = 2 To lrowCompare 'Loop through the value in the sheet you want to copy to
        ValCompare = CopyToSheet.Cells(j, "A").Value 'Get the value from the cell you want to copy to
        If Val = ValCompare Then 'Compare the values between the two workbooks, if the match (exact match) then
            CopyFromSheet.Activate
            CopyFromSheet.Range(Cells(CurrentRow, "A"), Cells(CurrentRow, "AA")).Copy 'Copy row from Column A to Column AA
            CopyToSheet.Activate 'Activate workbook to paste into
            CopyToSheet.Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(j, "AA")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste values into range.
        End If
    Next j
Next cl
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Deselect any copy selection
End Sub
```

My Example Setup is:

Worksheet that should be copied from.
[image]

Worksheet that should be copied to.
[image]